# extract filename out of raw data using regex

Tags: regex, splunk

This is my raw data:

```
h24-71-249-14.ca.shawcable.net - - [07/Mar/2004:22:29:13 - 0800] "GET /icons/gnu-head-tiny.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 3049

h24-71-249-14.ca.shawcable.net - - [07/Mar/2004:22:29:13 - 0800] "GET /icons/gnu-head-tiny HTTP/1.1" 200 3049
```

I want to be able to extract a file's name from the URI (if there is any, if there is not - ignore). The file can be any filetype (jpg, png, txt, etc.)

This is what I have so far:

```
(\"+)(.*?)(\.\w{1,3})
```

I know it is probably not a good idea to start my string from `"`, and it is probably the reason for my problem, so I'd like to get some help to fix my regex.

thank you!

Comment: Do you just want whatever is between GET and HTTP? then just ```/GET\s*([^\s\.]*\.\S*)\s*HTTP/``` and save your capture group

Comment: Also, is there a language requirement?

Comment: To get the filename without the last dot and 1-3 word characters `"GET \S+/(\S+)\.\w{1,3}` https://regex101.com/r/AT2y7x/1

Answer (score 0):

You can start the pattern from `"`, but you don't have to escape, repeat and capture it.

If you want the extension together with the filename, you can use a single capturing group.

You might use:

```
"GET \S+\/(\S+\.\w{1,3})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `"GET`  Match literally
- `\S+/` Match 1+ non whitespace chars and then match the last `/`
- `(\S+\.\w{1,3})` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars, a dot and 1-3 word chars
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/erUCil/1)

There is no language tagged, but for example using Javascript

```js
const regex = /"GET \S+\/(\S+\.\w{1,3})\b/;
[
  "h24-71-249-14.ca.shawcable.net - - [07/Mar/2004:22:29:13 - 0800] \"GET /icons/gnu-head-tiny.jpg HTTP/1.1\" 200 3049",
  "h24-71-249-14.ca.shawcable.net - - [07/Mar/2004:22:29:13 - 0800] \"GET /icons/gnu-head-tiny HTTP/1.1\" 200 3049"
].forEach(s => {
  let m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) console.log(m[1]);
})
```

---

When `\K` is supported, you can get the match only. According to the comments, this pattern gets the specific desired match:

```
\w{1,5} \S+\/\K\S+\.\w{3}\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\w{1,5}`  Match 1-5 word chars and a space
- `\S+\/` Match 1+ non whitespace chars and then the last `/`
- `\K` Reset the match buffer (forget what is matched until now)
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `\.\w{3}` Match a dot and 1-3 word characters
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DYkoA6/1)

Comment: thank you! but this regex catches the same as my regex catches.
I would like to catch only the file name, meaning:
"gnu-head-tiny.jpg" 
(from the first log line)

Comment: @orsa You have to get rhe group 1 value https://regex101.com/r/L5T2iQ/1 What is the tool or language?

Comment: I am trying to create a new field in SPLUNK called "file_name"

Comment: @orsa Try it like this to get the match only `"GET \S+\/\K\S+\.\w{1,3}\b` https://regex101.com/r/LW1PMT/1

Comment: this is great thanks!
what if I don't want to start from the "GET? 
(due to the fact that in a log list there are also POST logs)

Comment: @orsa Then you could use `"[A-Z]+ \S+\/\K\S+\.\w{1,3}\b` or list all the possible values. https://regex101.com/r/j2Eqj4/1

Comment: I figured it out, thank you so much!!

\"\w{1,5} \S+\/\K\S+\.\w{3}\b

Comment: @orsa I have updated the answer with the pattern that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Here are two options:

#### First

If you want what's between the `GET`  and  `HTTP`, this will do it:

```
| rex field=_raw "GET\s+(?<fname>\S+)\s+HTTP"
```

Start at the string literal `GET`, go one (or more) whitespaces, then put everything that's *not* a whitespace character (up until a whitespace sequence that ends in the string literal `HTTP`) into the new field `fname`.

Functionally, you can leave off the `\s+HTTP` from the regex, but for *fullness' sake*, you may want to choose to leave it in there.

#### Second

If you only want the ending filename, this is it:

```
| rex field=_raw "(?<fname>[\.\-\w]+)\s+HTTP"
```

This will match all instances of `.`, `-`, and any word character (`\w`) as many times as they are found before a sequence of whitespace characters (`\s+`) followed by the string literal `HTTP` into the new field `fname`.

Or, optionally (though more steps to find the match, it *might* be better in your case):

```
| rex field=_raw "(?<fname>[^\/]+)\s+HTTP"
```

This one will match anything that is not a front slash (`/`) up to the series of whitespaces followed by `HTTP` all into the new field `fname`.